# Sending client certificates through spring boot to external api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I have a Spring Boot application that does not currently have ssl enabled. I'm trying to add a new endpoint that will call an external API that requires x.509 certificate authentication. What I'm going for is to have something like the request prompt shown below appear when the user calls this specific endpoint from the browser, while the other endpoints in the spring application can be called as usual with no certificate. What I'm looking for is a way to pass the selected certificate through spring boot from the browser client to the external API. Is there a way to achieve this in Spring Boot?

[image]

Comment: SSL is an end to end communication, you can't pass it to some other endpoint. You could only route it, for example with an reverse proxy.

Comment: So I'm not trying to pass the SSL connection down the line. I'm trying to pass the cert so that the connection can be made further down the line if that makes sense.

Comment: Which cert? If you have the cert, you could give it to the developer of the external API, so it could be saved there. You don't need to pass it every time.